# Capturing print statement in f#

Tags: f#

I was wondering if there is a nice way to define a function `captureOutput` which takes a function `f` that may have contain print statements and return whatever it is that `f` printed. e.g.,

```
let f x = print "%s" x
let op = captureOutput (f "Hello World")

val op : string = "Hello World"
```

I was thinking that perhaps there is a nice way to do this asynchronously with `Console.ReadLine()` but I haven't been able to work anything out.

Cheers

EDIT:

Based on the comment of Fyodor Soikin, the following code does what I want:

```
let captureOutput f x =
    let newOut = new IO.StringWriter()
    Console.SetOut(newOut)
    f x
    Console.SetOut(Console.Out)
    newOut.ToString()
```

Comment: Have you tried [`Console.SetOut`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much for the reference! This is perfect for me.

Comment: Glad I could help. But this is essentially a hack, to be used with caution. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can temporarily replace the standard output writer via [`Console.SetOut`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout(v=vs.110).aspx).

But beware: this replacement will also affect code executing on other threads and capture their output as well, intermixed with your function's output. This is essentially what is known as a "hack".

If this is only for a very small utility that will never become more complex, then this is fine. But this should never become part of a production system. If you're developing a part of something complex, I recommend changing the function itself, parameterizing it over the printing function:

```
type Printer = abstract member print (fmt: StringFormat<'T, unit>) : 'T

let captureOutput f =
   let mutable output = ""
   let print s = output <- output + s
   f { new Printer with member _.print fmt = kprintf print fmt }
   output

let f x (p: Printer) = p.print "%s" x 
let op = captureOutput (f "Hello World")
```

(this example has to use an interface, because without it the `print` function would lose genericity)

Comment: Great, thanks. Indeed this is for a very small utility (grading student assignments for a class I'm TAing), so this solution is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Implementing @FyodorSoikin's suggestion (which I only saw *after* I had this written out):

```
let captureOutput f =
    use writer = new StringWriter()
    use restoreOut =
        let origOut = Console.Out
        { new IDisposable with member __.Dispose() = Console.SetOut origOut }
    Console.SetOut writer
    f ()
    writer.ToString ()

let f x () = printf "%s" x
let op = captureOutput (f "Hello World")
```

(N.b. an extra argument had to be added to `f` so that it could be partially applied – `captureOutput` must take a *function*, not a value).

An object-expression for `IDisposable` is used to wrap the cleanup so that calls to `f` are exception-safe.

Comment: Hi ildjarn, thanks for the reply! I'd also written my own solution in the main answer based on @FyodorSoikin's suggestion before seeing your response, they are very similar.

Comment: The `IDisposable` hack seems a bit verbose compared you `try ... finally` :-)

Comment: @FyodorSoikin : F# is the only language I use that has try-finally; I'm not really a fan and rarely think of it when writing code. /shrug :-]